# frame border width in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use `Xamarin.Forms`, I have `Image`. I want to Border with `Corner Radius` and `Border Width`. Can I do it ? I try to use `Frame`. It good but it has only `Border Width` = 1 and I can't change this. I know about `Effect`, but I don't want to use them. Can I do it For example with Rectangle or any way?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to use Effects? The problem of setting Frame's border width becomes quite trivial with them.

Comment: I thought there was a way without effects, only PCL. If there is no such method, I will make `Effects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to dance with FrameRenderer for Android and I found some solution.
Bad side is, that to be border color, width and corner radius variables visible inside MyFrameRenderer class, I had to create MyFrame:Frame class to affect only my own frame type. Close enough for my purpose... So:

```
namespace PROJECT
{
    public class MyFrame : Xamarin.Forms.Frame
    {
        public static float myFrameWidth = 2;
        public static float myCornerRadius = 12;
        public static Color myFrameColor = Color.Red;
        public static Color myBackgroundColor = Color.Black;

        public MyFrame() { }
    }
}
```

...

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PROJECT.MyFrame), typeof(PROJECT.Droid.MyFrameRenderer))]
namespace PROJECT.Droid
{
    class MyFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnDraw(Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            // canvas contains image of standard outline
            // to "hide" it, not efficent but sometimes "close enough solution"
            // is to overlay that outline by new one in our's page background color
            // then draw a new one in prefered style
            // or... just draw thicker one over the old

            var my1stPaint = new Android.Graphics.Paint();
            var my2ndPaint = new Android.Graphics.Paint();
            var backgroundPaint = new Android.Graphics.Paint();

            my1stPaint.AntiAlias = true;
            my1stPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            my1stPaint.StrokeWidth = MyFrame.myFrameWidth + 2;
            my1stPaint.Color = MyFrame.myFrameColor.ToAndroid();

            my2ndPaint.AntiAlias = true;
            my2ndPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            my2ndPaint.StrokeWidth = MyFrame.myFrameWidth;
            my2ndPaint.Color = MyFrame.myBackgroundColor.ToAndroid();

            backgroundPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            backgroundPaint.StrokeWidth = 4;
            backgroundPaint.Color = MyFrame.myBackgroundColor.ToAndroid();

            Rect oldBounds = new Rect();
            canvas.GetClipBounds(oldBounds);

            RectF oldOutlineBounds = new RectF();
            oldOutlineBounds.Set(oldBounds);

            RectF myOutlineBounds = new RectF();
            myOutlineBounds.Set(oldBounds);
            myOutlineBounds.Top += (int)my2ndPaint.StrokeWidth+3;
            myOutlineBounds.Bottom -= (int)my2ndPaint.StrokeWidth+3;
            myOutlineBounds.Left += (int)my2ndPaint.StrokeWidth+3;
            myOutlineBounds.Right -= (int)my2ndPaint.StrokeWidth+3;

            canvas.DrawRoundRect(oldOutlineBounds, 10, 10, backgroundPaint); //to "hide" old outline
            canvas.DrawRoundRect(myOutlineBounds, MyFrame.myCornerRadius, MyFrame.myCornerRadius, my1stPaint);
            canvas.DrawRoundRect(myOutlineBounds, MyFrame.myCornerRadius, MyFrame.myCornerRadius, my2ndPaint);

            base.OnDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can try something like this :

```
<Frame HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="25" Padding="2" BackgroundColor="#F69927">
    <Frame HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="23" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="12">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <!-- Content -->                
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 9):

Just wrap your frame into another frame giving it background color that you want you bordercolor to be. And give the wrapper-frame padding. Here is an example of the round image with border.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="60" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="2" IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <Frame CornerRadius="60" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Image Source="dp.jpg" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
    </Frame>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either create your own implementation with effects or extend the [FreshEssentials](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials) open source library. They have a control called [AdvancedFrame](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/FreshEssentials/Controls/AdvancedFrame.cs) that provides custom renderers for the Frame control on all platforms.

If you look at each platform specific project, you'll notice the `AdvancedFrameRenderer` classes that create bezier paths for rounded corner support. You'll just need to dive into the `Draw` method on each platform ([iOS](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/iOS/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendereriOS.cs#L23), [Android](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/Droid/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendererDroid.cs#L31)) and figure out how to set the stroke width.

It's easiest to start from Android since there the stroke width is defined in the code already ([on this line](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials/blob/master/src/Droid/Renderers/AdvancedFrameRendererDroid.cs#L100)). You'll just want to create a property for that in the AdvancedFrame control so you can have a different width on each control. I'm not sure how to set the stroke width on iOS but it's using UIBezierPath which should be rather easy to modify.